# Save PSD layer as PNG/JPG with Imagick depending on transparency

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have a script that uses Imagick to extract layers from .PSD files and saves them as .PNG files. The problem is that even for layers that have no transparency, PNGs are being saved, meaning increased file size. I'd prefer these files to be saved as JPEGs.

Can Imagick tell whether a layer in a PSD file would have any transparency or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `$imagick->getImageAlphaChannel()` if you want to detect if a source image has an alpha channel in it.

If you want to test if the alpha channel actually modifies the image i.e. contains something other than fully opaque, you can call `$image->getImageChannelStatistics();`. The values in that may only be valid if an image has an alpha channel

e.g. An image that has alpha, which affects the image has the following values for the alpha value.

```
[8] => Array ( 
    [mean] => 46867.721934066 
    [minima] => 0 
    [maxima] => 65535 
    [standardDeviation] => 26491.889090216 
    [depth] => 16 
)
```

An image that doesn't use transparency has the values

```
[8] => Array ( 

    [mean] => 0 
    [minima] => 3.3999999521444E+38 
    [maxima] => -3.3999999521444E+38 
    [standardDeviation] => 0 
    [depth] => 1 
)
```

which seem bogus.

So only an image that an alpha channel, and that doesn't have both 1 (or rather Qunatum value, i.e. probably 2 ^^ 16) for the mean in the alpha channel statistic and 0 for the standard deviation, would require saving with an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the PNG, it seems that running

```
identify -format '%[channels]' filename.png
```

effectively returns either **srgb** / **srgba**. So I'll use this to save to PNG, and then convert to JPEG if the value is **srgb**.